# I need EXS24 File format description for my utility

Tags: audiounit

In my recording studio I need serious customising and cataloging my .exs sample programs...

I want to write (C/C++/Swift... no matter) my own utility that would rename the names of samples (sample files, path etc) inside the .exs files (specific way).

So, I need to know EXS-file format (for read, manipulate with samples names string and rewrite). I don't find description file format.

Help.